# responsive flex column with svg

Tags: css, svg, flexbox

I'm trying to setup a panel on the right of my page. It will have some inline elements and a svg image in the middle.

I'd like the panel to be max 50% of width and 100% height. The SVG image should grow while preserving aspect ratio to fill the available height. Thus the container will get wider. It should stop growing when height is filled OR container width reach 50%.

Here is what I've come up with:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #333;
}

#viewport {
  background: #FFF;
  transition: all 200ms;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  animation: sizing 8s infinite;
}

.column {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.svgContainer {
  flex: 1;
}

.svgContainer svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

@keyframes sizing {
  0% {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  25% {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
  }
  75% {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="viewport">
  <div class="column">
    <h4>Some header</h4>
    <div class="svgContainer">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 300 214" width="300" height="214">
        <rect x="0" y="0"
          width="300" height="214" 
          stroke-width="5"
          stroke="#F00"
          rx="15" ry="15"
          fill="none"/>
         <circle cx="150" cy="107" r="80" stroke="#F00" stroke-width="5" fill="none"/>
    </svg>
    </div>
    <button>some button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've added an animation on the viewport size to illustrate several issues:

1. when viewport is narrow, the panel content overflow. I'd like the svg to shrink instead.
2. when panel is too high there is space between the svg and the button, I'd like to move this space under the button.

I did it with flexbox (`flex-direction: column` + `flex:1`) but it seems like I'm missing something

Answer (score 2):

For `when panel is too high there is space between the svg and the button, I'd like to move this space at the bottom.` : Remove the height from svg element.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #333;
}

#viewport {
  background: #FFF;
  transition: all 200ms;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  animation: sizing 8s infinite;
}

.column {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.svgContainer {
  flex: 1;
}

.svgContainer svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}


/* DEBUG */

#stopButton {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 2em;
}

@keyframes sizing {
  0% {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  25% {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
  }
  75% {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="viewport">
  <div class="column">
    <h4>Some header</h4>
    <div class="svgContainer">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 300 214" width="300">
        <rect x="0" y="0"
          width="300" height="214" 
          stroke-width="5"
          stroke="#F00"
          rx="15" ry="15"
          fill="none"/>
         <circle cx="150" cy="107" r="80" stroke="#F00" stroke-width="5" fill="none"/>
    </svg>
    </div>
    <button style="flex-shrink: 0;">some button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #333;
}

#viewport {
  background: #FFF;
  transition: all 200ms;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  animation: sizing 8s infinite;
}

.column {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.svgContainer {
  flex: 1;
}

.svgContainer svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}


/* DEBUG */

#stopButton {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 2em;
}

@keyframes sizing {
  0% {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  25% {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
  }
  75% {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="viewport">
  <div class="column">
    <h4>Some header</h4>
    <div class="svgContainer">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 300 214" width="300">
        <rect x="0" y="0"
          width="300" height="214" 
          stroke-width="5"
          stroke="#F00"
          rx="15" ry="15"
          fill="none"/>
         <circle cx="150" cy="107" r="80" stroke="#F00" stroke-width="5" fill="none"/>
    </svg>
    </div>
    <button>some button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. On latest chrome I see no difference here. The `flex-grow: 1` on the svg container is pushing the button at the bottom but I don't see how to preserve the growing behavior without it

Comment: Yeah i am trying to figure it out too. will let you know if i fix it

Comment: I made an edit to the question. I see what you did here with the svg always on top, but I'm also trying to have the button next to the svg

Comment: Check my second snippet is this what you need?

Comment: Thanks, it's close. The only problem left is that it will overflow in some configurations

Comment: I made a codepen to play around with the two issues in one screen: https://codepen.io/VincentCharpentier/pen/mjyBZz

Comment: Add overflow: auto; in case you want a scroll bar to come when the button exceeds the div

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a way to make the svg shrink when needed

Comment: It is shrinking ! but its maintaining the aspect ratio thats why the issue is coming